# Filter Dropdown values on List InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath, filter, dropdown

I have tried this example.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32961.sharepoint-filter-dropdown-values-on-list-infopath-form-based-on-current-user.aspx

But I came across with a problem. In Agency drop-down, it displays whatever mentioned fields when I create data connection. For example in my case I have mentioned Id and Agency. So in drop-down it displays Id and Agency together. Unfortunately Id cannot be un-ticked when we create data connection. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: do you need to display two fields (both ID and Agency fields)  in the drop down?

Comment: No. Only Agency I need to display. But right now both are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sivakumar , in the display name , select the field you want to display (Agency) in the drop down. try and let me know if you've issue.

[image]